# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on localhost request

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-cors-headers

I implemented django-allauth and the default template from /accounts works fine. But when I implemented custom templating and called the url /accounts/google/login from angular it throws an error

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am running my server in django 1.10.

I tried implementing django-cors-middleware but it still throws me the same error.

Is there a way or a custom middleware to fix it?

Comment: Did you follow this http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#google?

Comment: Yes, http://localhost:9000/accounts/google/login/callback/ is added in the authorised redirect uri.

Comment: You could maybe use this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi or disable your browser's security in some other way (for me, Chrome has been the nitpickiest). Or you could proxy the request through your own server, not make the request on the page via JS.

Comment: @LauriElias this works for me. Cheers